# ARM ads Error: L6242E

Tags: arm

I currently working on Intel xp32 platform using arm env. I found have errors like:

**My COMPILER OPTIONS**

```
REM -----  SET COMPILER OPTIONS
SET GCOPTIONS=-DLOGSYS_FLAG -D_SOFTPAY -D__arm  --thumb --diag_suppress 1,611,815,550,962,1300
```

**Error**

```
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object synctask.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attri
butes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte
datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object syncdial.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attri
butes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte
datatypes.
```

can anybody tell me how to solve it.

**I try change compiler**

> REM -----  SET COMPILER OPTIONS SET GCOPTIONS= --thumb -g+ --apcs
>   --adsabi --diag_suppress 1,611,815,550,962

**And new Erorr**

```
C:\ARM2\RVCT\PROGRAMS\2.0.1\359\WIN_32-PENTIUM\armlink" -o sp2000.axf -entry _vrxgo -scatter _vrxcc.sct -keep *(.0_vrx_pgmhdr) -keep *(.1_vrx_libtbl) -keep *(.2_vrx_libend) -via _vrxcc.via
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object V_misc.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object new.opi as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object delete.opi as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object Glue.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object V_card.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object V_gds.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object EMVCWrappers.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object MVT.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object EST.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object emvutils.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object emvfuncs.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object SYS.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object EMVSelection.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object EMVAIDList.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object EMVCmdSet.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object EMVRiskMgmtData.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Error: L6242E: Cannot link object EMVTxnStatus.o as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes.
   ... require 4-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes clashes with require 8-byte alignment of 8-byte datatypes.
Fatal error: L6045U: Invalid relocation #8 in EMVTxnStatus.o(.text). Type 102 is reserved for the GNU tool chain.
Finished: 17 information, 0 warning, 17 error and 1 fatal error messages.
```

Can Anybody help me solve this :(

Comment: Could you post some small code snippet, to allow us to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It looks like you mixing object files built with GCC with those built with ARMCC. Is this what you intend? It can probably be made to work but I need more details of what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Also, your armcc toolchain looks like a really old version, 2.0.1? That's nearly 10 years old, it's likely that GCC is now probably better than that.